# Area of a Trapezoid formula doesn't seem to work? (In calculating work)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

[image]

My Physics Teacher assigned me to find the work done by the force described by the above graph. Work is the integral of the force with respect to distance, or in other words, the area under the graph.  To calculate this area, apparently you have to break the shape into three rectangles and two triangles to get what they call the correct answer of 100J.

Why can't you use the formula for the area of the Trapezoid, A = (1/2)(b1 + b2)h ???

That would give you an answer of A = (1/2)(1 + 4)(30) = 75J which is incorrect.

Is this figure not drawn to scale or am I making some obvious error in applying the formula for the area of a Trapezoid?

Thank you.

Comment: As garyp points out, the shape under the graph is not a trapezoid. You could, however, split it up into a trapezoid (the part above P=15 N), and a rectangle (the part below P=15 N), if you wanted to.

Comment: Area trapezium 0 to 2 metre, area rectangle 2 to 3 metres and area trapezium 3 to 4 metres.

Answer (score 3):

A [trapezoid is a quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid).  It has four sides.  Your figure has six sides.  It is not a trapezoid.